# How to align text in middle (vertically)

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am struggling with this many hours now and still I can't find a solution. I've made this nice grid  that adjusts with text length and browser resising. The problem now is that I can't get text go the middle of the box.

I've tried everything.. I used several properties in order to achieve this but nothing worked.

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: "same as div";
```

The css code:

```
.parent {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  padding:18px 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  list-style-type:none;
  width:inherit;
  margin:5px;

}
```

Comment: Quick and simple: Center vertically with flexbox - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
.parent {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.child {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    padding:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:inherit;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:inherit;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><span>sometext</span></div>
    <div class="child">somemoretext somemoretext</div>
    <div class="child">sometext</div>
    <div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">somemoretext somemoretext somemoretext somemoretext</div>
    <div class="child">sometext</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is done with flex as ur jsfiddle. u can do it also easier with "parent display table and vertical align middle" and "child display table cell and van middle" removing ur flex styles.

Comment: Seems pretty good!! May I ask if this will work in most browsers ? :) Thank you so much for your input :)

Comment: u can check [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for the css compatibility! my opinion is tha flex is supported on many browsers and frameworks and i think its safe to use.. your rest css seems ok.

Comment: Thanks :) have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care that divs with multiple lines of text adjust their height to actual text content, use `height:100%` on your `child` elements.

If you need all your content to stay the same height, add

```
// Use any fixed value
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
```

If you need to change your fixed height in pixels whenver your window is resized, just use javascript to change the CSS rule (if using this method read [this](http://gomakethings.com/javascript-resize-performance/) first to not slow down your client when the window gets changed).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

margin:0 auto;

Comment: can you post the html for what your aligning so i can try for myself please?

Comment: on this link, the text is in the middle of the box?!

Comment: In the link I've added a second text in one box causing the rest boxes to increase their height. As a result the text in the other boxes stayed on the top and it didn't go in the middle so I am trying to figure out something but I am out of thoughts.